# With Amazon S3, can I prevent trolls/grievers from making millions of GET-requests with bots?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm working on a website that contains photo galleries, and these images are stored on Amazon S3. Since Amazon charges like $0.01 per 10k GET-requests, it seems that a potential troll could seriously drive up my costs with a bot that makes millions of page requests per day.

Is there an easy way to protect myself from this?

Answer (score 1):

As @mohan-shanmugam pointed out, you should use a CloudFront CDN with your origin as the S3 bucket. It is considered bad practice for external entities to hit S3 buckets directly.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html

With a CloudFront distribution, you can alter your S3 bucket's security policy to only allow access from the distribution. This will block direct access to S3 even if the URLs are known.

In reality, you would likely suffer from website performance way before needing to worry about additional charges as a direct DDOS attempt against S3 should result in AWS throttling API requests.

In addition, you can set up [AWS WAF](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/cloudfront-features.html) in front of your CloudFront distribution and use it for advanced control of security related concerns.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest strategy would be to create randomized URLs for your images.

You can serve these URLs with your page information. But they cannot be guessed by the bruteforcer and will usually lead to a 404.

so something like yoursite/images/long_random_string

Comment: But simply loading a webpage that contains images (usually 20-30) triggers a series of GET-requests to S3, right?

Comment: read about css sprites https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp

Help reduce calls to the image server for embedded images. There is no strategy for reducing s3 images. Other than maybe downloading a gzipped bundle and then using JS to unpack and update the page with the newly downloaded images. Quite complicated and nonstandard.

Answer (score 0):

Add aws Cloudfront service for your S3 object images. So it will retrieve the cached data from the edge location.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/MigrateS3ToCloudFront.html

Comment: +1 and https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-protect-your-web-application-against-ddos-attacks-by-using-amazon-route-53-and-a-content-delivery-network/

Comment: While CloudFront is an excellent service, if someone wants to abusively run up your bandwidth or per-request bill, this will have essentially no impact at all.  If anything, this would increase your theoretical exposure because CloudFront can handle much more traffic than S3 for a given bucket.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop a DoW (denial of wallet) attack, you will need to find a different (and better) solution.

You cannot prevent this type of attack with AWS, and I believe this is by design. After all, you don’t make billions without using some sort of dirty tactic. Don’t we all wish we could make money this way?

AWS S3 endpoints are accessible to the internet no matter what, as are CloudFront + WAF endpoints. You cannot put them behind a VPC. You will pay for all requests, (allowed and blocked) to S3 and CloudFront/WAF.